# How do I modify a file in place using shell?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I am using linux.

I have to convert html files to txt. So i am using html2txt command

I made a shell script called "converttohtml.sh"

```
    html2text -width 10000 $1 > $1
```

then i am planning to run find and convert all the files.

```
   find . -name "*.htm" -exec ./converttohtml.sh {} \;
```

but $1 > $1 redirecting is not working. If the input file is 1.htm (1.2kb), then the output file 1.htm is 0 bytes. but when i do on command line

```
    $ html2txt -width 10000 1.htm > 1.htm
```

it works fine. 1.htm shows only text. I dont know why $1 > $1 is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Processing the file and doing redirection at the same time will overwrite the file with 0 byte as shell processes redirection before running the `html2text` command which essentially means that even before `html2text` processing your file is 0 bytes.

Use it this way:

```
html2text -width 10000 "$1" > "$1.tmp" && mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

Comment: That means run next command only if previous command is successful.